# system() command inside a PHP script - calling a batch file...

Tags: php, linux, permissions, system

I am trying to make a `system('touch 1.test');` inside my server.
So I call `systest.php`:

```
<?php
      system('touch 1.test');
?>
```

**the file isn't created.**

it works perfectly when called through the command line:

```
/bin/php /public_html/systest.php
```

and it creates the file `1.test`.

Can it be a permissions error? some other kind of security issue?

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: Where is it creating the file when you run it by hand? Where do you expect it to create it when run by the webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the folder that the file is to be created in is not owned by Apache and it isn't writable then this will fail.

Make sure it has the correct permissions or it is done in a folder which is owned by apache or created by apache.

Comment: It doesn't have to be owned by apache, it just has to be writable by it.

Comment: But if it is owned by apache then it is writable by that group, if not then it has to be writable by everyone

Comment: Never heard of access control lists?

Comment: I pointed the file to writable area, it fixed the problem, thanks you guys!